# Unknown column 'asdf' in 'where clause' while executing a php script

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner for programming.
I were unable to solve the following error. The authentication_credentials table contains a column called 'id'. 
'asdf' is username I have provided in the browser page.
This has resulted in following error:

```
Unknown column 'asdf' in 'where clause'
```

while executing a php script

Please help...

```
$uname  = $_POST['uname'];
$query_request = "SELECT password FROM authentication_credentials WHERE id=$uname";
$query_result = mysql_query($query_request) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: One possible reason is that there is a `trigger` on table `authentication_credentials`.

Comment: mysql error check if your table and column and connections is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that `$uname` is a string Than your query is wrong `$name` have to be in single quete `''`

change that query to this

```
$query_request = "SELECT password FROM authentication_credentials WHERE id='$uname'";
```

Check thi ling for sql identifier http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

and one more thing mysqli_ does not magically secure your code. remember that.

Comment: because its a string that's why you have to enclose it in quotes.